# Summation $\sum_{i} ((i+1)^2)$ over given set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have a question about this summation:

$$\sum_{i} ((i+1)^2)$$ where $\{i \in S| f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S, f(x)=x\%5 \}$

How would I go about determining the upper limit of $i$? Does this mean that the sum is from $i=0$ to $i=5$, since the remainder of any integer when divided by $5$ will be between $0$ and $5$?

Comment: That sounds right -1, although your MathJax editing good use some practice! :)

Comment: I don't understand the set you've written. But, don't forget that the remainder is going to be between $0$ and $4$, as $5 \equiv 0$ mod $5$.

Comment: I apologize; the lower limit is not assigned a value at the start- I edited that. Also, the I in I->S is referring to the set of all integers.